# Find statement in matlab and multiple conditions

Tags: matlab, find, conditional-statements

The following code is embedded in a function

```
rsp = find(response_times >= current1 & response_times < current2 & response_times ~= current2);
```

Here, I am looking for the indices of responses that occur between `current1` and `current2`, where `current1` and `current2` are times such as 16.22 and 16.32, respectively, and the response times can be equal to `current1` but not `current2`.

For the most part this works as intended, however, every so often it pulls an index of a value equal to `current2`.

Does anyone know why this might be the case or how I can improve this one line of code to fix it.

Here is an example array this code operates on:

```
response_times = [ 8.73000000000000
    11.4300000000000    13.4800000000000    
    14.7900000000000    16.3200000000000    
    18.0400000000000    20.3800000000000    
    20.9900000000000    21.3400000000000    
    24.2800000000000    24.6800000000000 ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not actually (exactly) equal to `current2`.  You generally shouldn't compare floating point numbers for equality. Read [this article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/05/why-do-computers-suck-at-math.html) for more information, but the essence of the problem is that most values cannot be represented *exactly* with a floating point representation (i.e.  IEEE 754), hence it is not advisable to test for equality. Inequalities are fine. There is actually a neat [mini-site](http://floating-point-gui.de/) dedicated to providing a basic explanation of the issue.

For the Stack Overflow [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab) version of the explanation see this Q&A, entitled ["Why is 24.0000 not equal to 24.0000 in MATLAB?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686439/why-is-24-0000-not-equal-to-24-0000-in-matlab). It's quite an interesting read!

To verify that your inequality is actually working, have it compute `abs(response_times-current2)` and you should find that the value is not zero in those cases, but rather something small like 1.35e-15. If you want to reject these "too close" values, include a test such as `(current2-response_times)>tol` and set `tol` to something large enough to reject these points.

Comment: I see. I've read up on this; however, it doesn't change the fact that I need this function to work as intended. Is there a way to tell matlab to work with decimal data?

Comment: @cwdaniels Well, it is working and there is no way to change it unless you round to integers. With decimal data, you just have to set a threshold.  When comparing two floats for equality, it is a common workaround to do something like `abs(f1-f2)<tol` where `tol` is a small number.  So, in your case you could do something like `(current2-response_times)>tol` and set `tol` low enough to reject these too close points.

Comment: I converted all my values to integers which fixed part of my problem. I realized the substantial loss of data I was experiencing was actually due to a condition statement early in the function that asked if a certain value was less than or greater than 25...it would throw out trials in which that occurred.